# deploying sample application endeca

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

I’m trying to deploy the sample application in `endeca`:

> ./deploy.sh –app
>   /common/endeca/ToolsAndFrameworks/3.1.2/reference/discover-data/deploy.xml

I keep getting the below error :

> ./deploy.sh: 41: ./deploy.sh:
>   /common/endeca/PlatformServices/6.1.4/perl/bin/: Permission denied

Need help on how to fix this.

Comment: Check the line 41. It must call another script where you have not provided execution permission. To provide execution permission to a file, "chmod u+x filename"

Comment: Also make sure your `PERL5LIB` environment variable is set correctly